# The file is on a network path that is not supported for database files

Tags: sql-server

I am receiving this error message while creating DB from a `.mdf` and `.ldf` files located on a network drive.

Query executed:

```
create database DatabaseName ON
  (FileName = '\\gyancluster-sql\g$\Backup\WSS_Content_DB.mdf'),
  (FileName = '\\gyancluster-sql\g$\Backup\WSS_Content_DB_log.ldf')
  for attach
GO
```

Error

> The file "\gyancluster-sql\g$\Backup\WSS_Content_DB.mdf" is on a
>   network path that is not supported for database files.

Comment: You don't make clear what your question is. However, [this Microsoft article gives you chapter and verse](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304261) and will probably help you.

Comment: The `.mdf` and `.ldf` file need to be on one of the **local disks** of the server machine where SQL Server runs. It's not supported to have those on network shares.

Answer (score 4):

So what is your problem? What is the question? No question there - just dumping a sentence ;)

I mean, without wanting to sound too sarcastic, but you CAN read, or?

> The file "\gyancluster-sql\g$\Backup\WSS_Content_DB.mdf" is on a network path that is not supported for database 
>   files.

That is pretty clear, isn't it? It is not supported - for VERY good reasons, btw., until now.

Are you asking us now whether MS lies? No, they do not lie - this is not supported. They REALLY MEAN what they say.

There are ways around (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304261) but that is it ;)

Do you want us to reword the error message? Maybe into "dude, that wont worx, not cool, see"? Clearer?

Seriously - soudns harsh, but I always wonder why people do not actually READ the error message.

Comment: I had previously executed the same command. And it did execute.

Answer (score 1):

Use DBCC TRACEON(1807) before trying to create the Database.

Also, you can add the linea "-t 1807" to the MSSQL server startup parameters, it will make the change permanent. The command above let you use network storage, but on a reboot you will lose the flag.

Comment: Well, this seem to work. I'm just trying to restore a database not to be used on any production stuff.

Comment: Can't believe I had the exact same problem again and forgot. Tried to google again and found this AGAIN :D

Answer (score 0):

You are lucky that the OS is warning you that opening database files directly over a network is a bad idea. Older database api's let you do that with no warning and then network users of that database application are forever blighted with corrupt databases.

Comment: This is not really a helpful answer. The OS is not warning them, but MS SQL is actually indicating that it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

If \gyancluster-sql\g$ refers for Local Disk G on the computer gyancluster-sql which also happens to be where the sql service is running, then you really should be using

```
create database DatabaseName ON
  (FileName = 'G:\Backup\WSS_Content_DB.mdf'),
  (FileName = 'G:\Backup\WSS_Content_DB_log.ldf')
  for attach
 GO
```

Note this remains true even if you are running the script from another computer.

It would still be a bad idea, but you may able to use the UNC names, but only if the service under which sql is running is able to access the share(eg if running under the Domain Administrator account), but that is normally considered an unnecessary security risk.

If you are really trying to store the database on network device, then obviously that means the sql service does need access to the share, so that would be the first thing to check, but you also need to read the Microsoft article which Chris Dickson has pointed you to (ie http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304261) which details when this is supported.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the database file over network shared, the following post explain step by step how to do it.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varund/2010/09/02/create-a-sql-server-database-on-a-network-shared-drive/

The same post explains the risks to do it.

I hope this helps

Regards